# Retornar linhas de um dataframe que não constam em outro dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Basicamente, tenho um DataFrame(Base de dados) que contem todos os dados cadastrado no meu sistema:

```
data = {"Id": ["01", "02", "03", "04",'05'],"Fruta": ['Maçã','Abacaxi','Banana','Laranja','Morango']}
base_dados = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(base_dados)

    Id  Fruta
0   01  Maçã
1   02  Abacaxi
2   03  Banana
3   04  Laranja
4   05  Morango
```

E possuo outro DataFrame(Producao) com os itens produzidos que contém itens que já consta no banco, como itens novos que não consta lá, no exemplo citei a **Melancia** e o **Melão**.

```
data = {"Id": ["01", "03",'05','06','07'],"Fruta": ['Maçã','Banana','Morango','Melancia','Melao']}
producao = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(producao)

    Id  Fruta
0   01  Maçã
1   03  Banana
2   05  Morango
3   06  Melancia
4   07  Melao
```

O que eu preciso, é captar no python atraves do pandas, captar apenas os itens que não consta na base de dados ainda para que eu possa estar fazendo o tratamento dele no futuro.

Exemplo do resulto esperado:

```
    Id  Fruta
0   06  Melancia
1   07  Melao
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso da seguinte forma:

```
producao.loc[~producao['Id'].isin(base_dados['Id'])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

output do código acima:

```
   Id     Fruta
0  06  Melancia
1  07     Melao
```

Em resumo: a expressão `producao['Id'].isin(base_dados['Id'])` retorna uma coluna booleana de todos os `Id`s da tabela `producao` que constam na coluna `Id` da tabela `base_dados`. Como queremos os `Id`s que NÃO constam na tabela `base_dados`, usamos o operador `~` para inverter os valores booleanos da coluna.

Aí é só passar essa coluna para `produção.loc`. O `reset_index` eu fiz apenas para que o índice do DataFrame resultante seja igual ao seu exemplo de output esperado.

Comment: Amigo, é exatamente isso, funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
base_dados2 = base_dados[["Id","Fruta"]].where(base_dados["Id"]=="01").dropna()
```

Resumindo: o dataframe base_dados2 recebe as colunas "Id" e "Fruta" do dataframe base_dados onde tem apenas a condição que você deseja, no caso onde o "Id" é igual a "01" e o dropna() no final serve para a base_dados2 receber apenas os valores que satisfação a condição.

Comment: Acredito que essa seja a ideia mesmo, mas no '''where(base_dados["Id"]=="01").dropna()''', eu não vou ter como saber o numero da ID

Comment: Esse é só um exemplo, você pode colocar a condição que quiser dentro do where, até mesmo comparando os valores de dois dataframes, não precisa ser da coluna Id pode ser a coluna que você desejar.

Comment: No caso eu fiz assim: base_dados2 = base_dados[["Id","Fruta"]].where(base_dados[["Id","Fruta"]].==producao[["Id","Fruta"]]).dropna()
Mas retorna erro "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"
Eu preciso receber em base_dados2 os itens de producao que não possui em base_dados

Comment: Acho que você quer algo assim: base_dados2 = base_dados[["Id","Fruta"]].where(~base_dados["Fruta"].isin(producao["Fruta"])).dropna()

Comment: Amigo, primeiramente obrigado pela atenção que você está me dando, o codigo que vc colocou por ultimo funcionou trazendo os itens que já tinha do base_dados, eu queria pegar os itens de producao que NÃO consta em base_dados, como exemplo traria o itens:     
     Id  Fruta
0   06  Melancia
1   07  Melao

Comment: To aqui pra ajudar parceiro, tenta essa, acho que agora entendi o que você quer: data2 = producao[["Id","Fruta"]].where(~producao["Fruta"].isin(base_dados["Fruta"])).dropna()